# Protractor - Cucumber : Annoying ECONNREFUSED Errors while working as expected

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, integration-testing, bdd, protractor

I'm trying to integrate Cucumber with protractor, While the setup is working as expected (the test fail and succeed normally), I'm getting annoying ECONNREFUSED errors that makes my feedback unreadable.

- Question 1: What't ECONNREFUSED's error exact meaning? I don't really understand the feedback and I couldn't find good documentation for it.
- Question 2: What could be the problem with my setup? Is my setup proper?
- Question 3: Has anyone run BDD tests in vagrant box with cucumber over protractor? Example code please :)

**Dependencies**

```
npm i protractor cucumber selenium-webdriver chai chai-as-promised express grunt-protractor-runner protractor-cucumber --save-dev
```

As you see I'm running my commands via grunt inside a vagrant box. The vagrant box has only firefox, I'm not sure if that's a problem, protractor was running just fine before.

**Terminal Feedback**

```
[vagrant@vagrant web-src]$ grunt protractor:singlerun
Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

Feature: Blog
  As a user
  I want to visit blog
  So that I can stay informed about a topic


  Scenario: A disclaimer scenario   # tests/e2e/cucumber/features/Blog.feature:6

/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131
  var session = webdriver.promise.controlFlow().execute(function() {
                                                ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:49)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:111:30)
    at Builder.build (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:106:20)
    at HostedDriverProvider.getDriver (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/hosted.js:63:9)
    at /var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:241:41
    at _fulfilled (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /var/www/miyagi/web-src/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:573:44
>> 
>> Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.

Done, without errors.
[vagrant@vagrant web-src]$
```

**Protractor Config**

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['../cucumber/features/*.feature'],
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'firefox'
  }],
  onPrepare: function() {
    var width = 1024;
    var height = 600;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    // implicit and page load timeouts
    browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);

    // for non-angular page
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  },
  framework: 'cucumber',
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: '../cucumber/features/*.steps.js',
    format: 'pretty'
  }
};
```

**Grunt task**

```
protractor: {
            options: {
              configFile: '<%=tests %>/e2e/protractor/config.js', // Default config file
              noColor: false,     // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output
              keepAlive: true
            },
            auto : {
                keepAlive: true // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
            },
            singlerun: {}
        },
```

**Feature**

```
Feature: Blog
  As a user
  I want to visit blog
  So that I can stay informed about a topic

  Scenario: A disclaimer scenario
    Given I visit blog
    Then I should see a disclaimer
```

**Steps**

```
//http://chaijs.com/
var chai = require('chai');

//https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function() {
  var url = 'http://dev.com/search',
  searched = url + '#/?q=food&page_number=1&sort=relevance',
  driver,
  resultsA, resultsB, resultsC,
  page,
  site;




  this.Given(/^I visit blog$/, function(callback) {
    browser.get(url);
    driver = browser.driver;
    browser.getTitle()
      .then(function ( title ) {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal(arg1).and.notify(callback);
      });
  });

  this.Then(/^I should see a disclaimer$/, function(callback) {
    element( by.css ( '.disclaimer' ) )
      .isDisplayed()
      .then(function (el) {
        expect(el).to.have.length(1);
        callback();
      });
  });
};
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You never mentioned setting up a local selenium server. Did you forget it?

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
```

Just let that run in its own terminal window, and try running your tests again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It happens to setup a selenium server from vagrant automatically, when I run the two commands I'm getting `Error:no display specified` and I'm not getting any results, Without running the commands I'm getting my results, but I'm also getting the ECONNREFUSED Errors

Comment: If you're in a VM you may need to run [`xvfb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), an "xserver virtual frame buffer" for running headless firefox/chrome browsers in GUI-less server environments.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you already have another instance of webdriver running? Or a firewall that is blocking the connection?

This is a working example that I found. However it is in .coffee
https://github.com/whyvez/angular-cucumber-example